# What does ${i%.*} do in this context?

Tags: bash, parameter-expansion

I'm learning a bit about running a bash script in a linux terminal, specifically in the context of converting audio video files.

I came across this command here on SO that does exactly what I want. However, I'd like to understand it better:

`for i in *.avi; do ffmpeg -i "$i" "${i%.*}.mp4"; done`

Now, this is obviously a `for-loop` and I get the first `*` wildcard. I get the `do` block. But what I don't quite understand is `${i%.*}`. Specifically, what does the `%.*` bit do in the output location? Why not use `${i}.mp4` instead?

Comment: you may find this useful: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and it removes everything starting from the last dot (ie. extension). Try the following:

```
$ i="foo.bar.baz"
$ echo ${i%.*}
foo.bar
```

Author of the original code (`"${i%.*}.mp4"`) apparently wanted to replace original extension with `.mp4` so the original extension is removed and `.mp4` is appended.

Comment: Rather “parameter expansion”

Answer (score 1):

**Parameter expansion**

*${parameter%word}*

*${parameter%%word}*

> The word is expanded to produce a pattern and matched according to the rules described below (see Pattern Matching). If the **pattern matches a trailing portion** of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘%’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘%%’ case) **deleted**.